# Java abstract method and interface

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface `HTTPSequence`. I also have an abstract class `AbstractHTTPFactory` which in turn has an abstract method returning `ArrayList<HTTPSequence>`. In classes derived from `AbstractHTTPFactory` I want to override those methods to return `ArrayList<[Class implementing HTTPSequence]>`.

Is it possible ? Now compiler gives my an error suggesting that I change overriden methods signature to `HTTPSequence`.

```
// abstract class with abstract method returning ArrayList of objects implementing interface
abstract public class AbstractHTTPFactory {
    abstract ArrayList<HTTPSequence> make();
}
// Specific class that returns ArrayList of objects of the class implementing HTTPSequence
public class RecipesHTTPFactory extends AbstractHTTPFactory{
    public ArrayList<Recipe> make() {
    }
}
// interface
public interface HTTPSequence {
}
// one of the classes implementing the above interface
public class Recipe implements HTTPSequence {
}
```

And the message Eclipse gives me is:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - The return type is incompatible with AbstractHTTPFactory.make()
>     - implements ....ider.AbstractHTTPFactory.make

Comment: Why would you want to just return a non-generic `ArrayList`? That defeats the purpose of generics!

Comment: Some sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: And an exact compiler message. Hand-waving isn't helping, @user971155

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your AbstractClass method to return `ArrayList<? extends Interface>`, and then you do not have to change the derived class method signatures

Comment: seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: there is a time limit, okay can except now

Answer (score 0):

The following design would allow you to avoid having to return a wildcarded generic type, which are of [limited use to the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type):

```
abstract public class AbstractHTTPFactory<T extends HTTPSequence> {
    abstract ArrayList<T> make();
}

public class RecipesHTTPFactory extends AbstractHTTPFactory<Recipe> {
    public ArrayList<Recipe> make() { ... }
}
```

Now you can call `new RecipesHTTPFactory().make()` and get back an `ArrayList<Recipe>` instead of an `ArrayList<? extends HTTPSequence>`.

Also note that unless the caller specifically expects an `ArrayList`, [it is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992479/697449) for `make()` to return a `List<T>`.