# Can't add object implementing interface A to a Collection<? extends A>

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why can't I add the a object to the collection? Since the class B is something that extends A.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestGeneric
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Collection<? extends A> collection = new ArrayList<A>();
    A a = new B();
    collection.add(a);
  }

  private static class B implements A {
    public int getValue() { return 0; }
  }
}

interface A { int getValue(); }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add value to the Java collection with wildcard generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type). See also: [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 4):

Because of the following reason:

```
Collection<? extends A> coll = new ArrayList<C>(); // C extends A

coll.add(new B()); // B extends A, but doesn't extend C. Oops.
```

However, since the compiler knows that coll only has elements that extends A, you can still retrieve them as As.

```
A myA = coll.get();  // No problem, it might be B or C, but they both extend A
```

Answer (score 3):

Short and simple explanation:

`<? extends A>` means: some **specific but unknown** type that extends `A`.  Could be `A` itself or any of its subtypes.  Therefore, you cannot insert **any** element in this collection: the compiler can't know what type would be legal for parameters for the `add(object)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind: [Provider extends consumer super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) (also known as PECS)

You want to **put** things into the collection, so the collection is a **consumer**.

```
    Collection<? super A> collection = new ArrayList<A>();
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/1667004) answer

> Case 2: You want to add things to the collection.
>    Then the list is a consumer, so you should use a `Collection<? super Thing>`.
>
> The reasoning here is that unlike `Collection<? extends Thing>`, `Collection<? super Thing>` can always hold a `Thing` no matter what the actual parameterized type is. Here you don't care what is already in the list as long as it will allow a `Thing` to be added; this is what `? super Thing` guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

**if you have `<? extends A>`  then at this point compiler does not know what is the subclass of `A` that is getting used. So it's not safe to add any object to collection except `null`.**

**You can't add any object to `List<? extends T>` because you can't guarantee what kind of List it is really pointing to, so you can't guarantee that the object is allowed in that List. The only "guarantee" is that you can only read from it and you'll get a `T` or `subclass of T`.**

`List<? extends Number>` can be implemented by three:

`List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();`  // Number "extends" Number
`List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` // Integer extends Number
`List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Double>();`  // Double extends Number

So if it is `new ArrayList<Double>()` and you are adding `integer` so it's an error, so it's safe for compiler to restrict the access to only reading no adding.

And adding is also safe because we know the parent class hence we can assign any child class to parent class reference as below:

`Parent p = new Child();` //this is safe

hence in `List<? extends Number>`  we know all the elements inside the collection are somehow extending `Number` hence we can read it because we can assign an instance of child class to parent class reference.