# Generic JUnit tests

Tags: java, generics, junit

I've got an abstract generic collections class `GCollection`, and a class that extends that called `GStack`.

To test the implementation I have an abstract JUnit test class, which I extend for each of the `GCollection` implementations I do:

```
public abstract class GCollectionTest<T extends GCollection<E>, E> {
    private GCollection<? extends Object> collection;
    protected abstract GCollection<T> createInstance();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        collection = createInstance();
    }

    // Tests down here.
```

This is extended like so:

```
public class GStackCollectionInterfaceTest<S extends GCollection<E>> {
    protected GDSStack<? extends Object> createInstance() {
        return new GDSStack<String>();
    }
}
```

I test first with a `GStack` holding `String` objects, then re-run the tests with `Date` objects to ensure it works with different object types.

```
@Test
public void testIsEmpty() {
    assertTrue(collection.isEmpty()); // Fresh Stack should hold no objects
    collection.add(new String("Foo")); // Error here.
    assertFalse(collection.isEmpty());
}
```

The error given is:

> The method add(capture#24-of ? extends Object) in the type GCollection is not applicable for the arguments (String)

My understanding of the error is that I can't put a `String` object into a `GCollection<T extends GCollection<E>>` object, but I don't think that's what I'm trying to do.

#### What am I doing wrong?

How can I solve this error while maintaining tests that are as generic as possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of collection is `GCollection<? extends Object>`. It is not possible to add anything to this collection, see: [can't add value to the java collection with wildcard generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type).

There's no need for wildcards or bounds in the subclass so you can simplify the generics. Something like:

```
abstract class GCollectionTest<T> {
    protected Collection<T> collection;

    protected abstract Collection<T> createCollection();
    protected abstract T createObject();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        collection = createCollection();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
        assertTrue(collection.isEmpty());
        collection.add(createObject());
        assertFalse(collection.isEmpty());
    }
}

class GStackCollectionInterfaceTest extends GCollectionTest<String> {
    protected GDSStack<String> createCollection() {
        return new GDSStack<String>();
    }

    protected String createObject() {
        return new String("123");
    }
}
```

Using different types with the collection is allowed because of the generic type, and checked by the compiler, so it doesn't really need testing. I would just test the different container types, but you could create another subclass that uses `Date` instead of `String`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add `null`? `null` is an instance of every class.