# Change user roles by userDetailsManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, roles

I would like to change the role of the user. Changing role of the user in the database. Everything is based on Spring Security.

My code:

```
UserDetails user = userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(userData.getUser().getUsername());

user.getAuthorities().add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));

userDetailsManager.updateUser(user);
```

Error:

```
Error:(99, 30) java: method add in interface java.util.Collection<E> cannot be applied to
given types;
  required: capture#1 of ? extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
  found: org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
  reason: actual argument    
org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority cannot be converted to   
capture#1 of ? extends org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority by method   
invocation conversion
```

I don't know why is this error. How can otherwise change the role for the user?

Comment: Do SimpleGrantedAuthority extends GrantedAuthority? Can you show it's code.

Comment: Yes, it implementa this interface.

Comment: Try 
`GrantedAuthority ga = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
user.getAuthorities().add(ga);`

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can update the role of a given user by creating a new UserDetails object from their existing one, then calling UserDetailsManager.updateUser() method as follows:

```
    UserDetails oldDetails = userDetailsManager.loadUserByUsername(user);
    UserDetails newDetails = new User(user, oldDetails.getPassword(),  newRole);
    userDetailsManager.updateUser(newDetails);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. the issue is that you can't add a known type into a list that holds an unknown type. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3716945/755183)
2. User is immutable, so in order to modify you should clone existing user and use new roles