# Nested generics and wildcards

Tags: java, generics

I have seen several questions on this topic, but still can't figure out how to solve this problem. I define and initialize my variable as:

```
Queue<? extends Map<String, String>> q = new LinkedList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

And it compiles. But then:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("foo", "bar"); 
q.add(m);
```

reports a compilation error: `no suitable method found for add(Map<String,String>)`.

EDIT:

I think this is different to [Can't add value to the Java collection with wildcard generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3716920/1588163), because the generics are not nested in that question.

Furthermore, the accepted answer teaches that the specific implementation of a template class can be omited in some declarations. You won't find this teaching on the question marked as duplicate of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` means "unknown type". Since the type is unknown, the compiler can't guarantee that the type is `Map<String, String>`. So it refuses to let you add anything in the queue, since it could compromise its type-safety.

Your variable should be declared as

```
Queue<Map<String, String>> q = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
```

or simply, if you're on Java 7 or later

```
Queue<Map<String, String>> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Awesome! Of course! I didn't know I could postpone the declaration of the implementation of the map at this point. Thank you.