# Insert a BaseClass instance into a List<? extends BaseClass> (Java)

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance

I have a `List<? extends MyClass> list` and I want to add into this list objects whose class extends `MyClass` and objects which are instances of `MyClass`:

```
list.add(new ClassThatExtendsMyClass());
list.add(new MyClass());
```

but eclipse shows the build error:

> The method add(capture#9-of ? extends MyClass) in the
>   type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (MyClass)

How can I get around this?

Comment: have a look here, it's to do with the implementation of generics. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3716945/4112645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java keyword **extends** in generic type of reference is used to restrict actual generic type realization to be **no less derived** than the named type. Especially it can be a subclass. One should use it in case type is used to **extract** values and operate on them. You then use the interface of the base class not concerning the actual type (realization/implementation) of that class.

When you've got a specific class and need to **pass** (put) into collection, or other generic class object, the reference to point at that object should have **super** keyword, which restricts the actual object to be **no more derived** than the named type.

Code example below. Assume we have classes `Base` and `Derived`, where `Derived extends Base`, class `Base` have an interface method `foo()` and both have default constructor.

```
void service() {
    List<Base> theList = new ArrayList<Base>();

    produceObjects(theList);
    consumeObjects(theList);
}

void produceObjects(List<? super Base> consumerList) {
    consumerList.add(new Derived());
}

void consumeObjects(List<? extends Base> producerList) {
    for (Base base : producerList) {
        base.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your reference as `List<MyClass>`.

You'll be able to add anything extending `MyClass`, including instances of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. `List<? extends MyClass> list` could actually point to a `ArrayList<ClassThatExtendsMyClass>`. Which can't hold instances of some other subclass of MyClass.

```
List<? extends Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(Long.valueOf(2)); // not possible since 'Integer' array can't hold Longs
```

If you want to add things you should declare your variable 'list' as `List<? super MyClass>`. This will enable you to add any subclass of 'MyClass' into the list.

```
List<? super Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
numbers.add(Long.valueOf(2));
```

This is known as the 'get' and 'put' principle. If you want to 'get' stuff you need to have the `List<? extends MyClass>` syntax whilst if you want to 'put' stuff you need to have the `List<? super MyClass>` syntax. Ofcourse if you need to do both then you need to use `List<MyClass>` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<MyClass>
```

It should work

Comment: Why? Please explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Define it this way:

```
List<MyClass> list
```