# What type does getClass return?

Tags: java, generics

Here is my code:

```
Set<Class<Event>> s = new HashSet<>();             
Set<Class<? extends Event>> s2 = new HashSet<>();
Event e = new Event();                         

s.add(e.getClass());   // #1
s2.add(e.getClass());  // #2

class Event {
    // ...
}
```

Why does the compiler raise an error on the statement `#1`?

I'm using Java 7.

Comment: Possible duplciate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716920/cant-add-value-to-the-java-collection-with-wildcard-generic-type

Comment: @TheLostMind It's a custom Event class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take a look at [documentation of `getClass()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) you will see that

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> ```
> Number n = 0; 
> Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass();
> ```

So result of `e.getClass()` will be `Class<? extends Event>` which is precisely what `Set<Class<? extends Event>> s2` is suppose to store. That is why

```
s2.add(e.getClass());   // OK
```

works fine.

---

But in case of `Set<Class<Event>> s` things are little different. It can store only `Class<Event>`. Allowing it to store objects from `Class<? extends Event>` reference would be very dangerous in terms of type-security.

Take a look at this example (for easier understanding lets replace `Class` with `List` and our `Action` instances will be `Animal`s like `Dog` and `Cat`).

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<? extends Animal> generalList = dogs;

Set<List<Animal>> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Now lets assume that `Set<List<Animal>> set` can store `List<? extends Animal>`

```
set.add(generalList);
```

Now we are able to do something horrible as

```
for (List<Animal> animalList : set){
    animalList.add(new Cat()); // I just placed Cat in container full of Dogs!
}
```

Remember our `List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();` list? Now it contains `Cat` so if I do:

```
for (Dog dog : dogs){
    dog.speak();
}
```

I will probably see something similar to

> wof
> woof
> Woof
> Meow! (psst: Get me out of here!)
> ...

or instead of `Meow!` some exception like `NoSuchMethodException` or most probably `ClassCastException: Cat cannot be cast to Dog`.

So as you see allowing this mechanism wouldn't be very wise.

Comment: I would prefer seeing the `NoSuchMethodException` or any kind of bug instead of being blocked by the compiler. It seems to me I'm "over-protected" by the compiler.

Comment: Well, compiler can be tricked if you want with casting `s.add((Class<Event>) e.getClass());` no one stops you from doing your own mistakes now since generics are almost only compilation time tool :)

Comment: Anyway entire purpose of generics is to ensure type-safety so this mechanism looks fine for me.

Comment: If the compiler didn't have this behavior, posts would exist telling "why the compiler doesn't alert me...". I think an annotation like '@RelaxIKnowWhatIDo' would give us (me?) some flexibility.

Comment: One interesting aspect I'd like to point out is *"where |X| is the **erasure**"*. This is important if `X` happens to be a type variable. For example, `<T> Class<? extends T> m(T t) { return t.getClass(); }` won't compile but `<T extends Number> Class<? extends Number> m(T t) { return t.getClass(); }` will compile. Just a subtle technicality and it doesn't have an effect on the OP's snippet.